# How do I toggle div visibility and image source at the same time?

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jquery and I'm struggling with this page: http://www.revolutionlasvegas.com/instructors2.php

I have the divs with the bios toggling just fine but at the same time I want the image that was clicked on to change. And when another image is clicked, that one will change and the current one will change back to its original. Doesn't seem like this should be such an uncommon thing to do but I can't seem to find or figure out the answer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

```
 <script>
        function showonlyone(thechosenone) {
             $('.bio').each(function(index) {
                  if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
                       $(this).show(200);
                  }
                  else {
                       $(this).hide(600);
                  }
             });
         }
         </script>
        <div id="light_blue">
        <div class="randomordercontent group1"><a id="pic1" href="javascript:showonlyone('bio1');"><img src="images/instructors/thumb_damian.jpg" width="198" height="300" alt="" class="inst_thumbs"></a></div>
        <div class="randomordercontent group1"><a id="pic2" href="javascript:showonlyone('bio2');"><img src="images/instructors/thumb_martie.jpg" width="198" height="300" alt="" class="inst_thumbs"></a></div>
        <div class="randomordercontent group1"><a id="pic3" href="javascript:showonlyone('bio3');"><img src="images/instructors/thumb_ray.jpg" width="198" height="300" alt="" class="inst_thumbs"></a></div>
        <div class="randomordercontent group1"><a id="pic4" href="javascript:showonlyone('bio4');"><img src="images/instructors/thumb_debi.jpg" width="198" height="300" alt="" class="inst_thumbs"></a></div>
        <div class="randomordercontent group1"><a id="pic5" href="javascript:showonlyone('bio5');"><img src="images/instructors/thumb_stetson.jpg" width="198" height="300" alt="" class="inst_thumbs"></a></div>
        </div>

        <div class="bio" id="bio1" style="display: none"><h1 style="font-weight:bold">Damian Hill</h1></br></br></div>
        <div class="bio" id="bio2" style="display: none"><h1 style="font-weight:bold">Martie</h1></br></br></div>
        <div class="bio" id="bio3" style="display: none"><h1 style="font-weight:bold">Ray Chargualaf Jr</h1></br></br></div>
        <div class="bio" id="bio4" style="display: none"><h1 style="font-weight:bold">Debi Scaletta</h1></br></br></div>
        <div class="bio" id="bio5" style="display: none"><h1 style="font-weight:bold">Stetson</h1></br></br></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        randomordercontentdisplay.init()
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you can save src of the image in temp variable and then restore on clicking any other image.. and do replace the image on anchor click....

    function showonlyone(thechosenone, ClickedAnchorID) {
    var temp;
    $('.bio').each(function(index) {
    if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
    $(this).show(200);
    temp = $("#ClickedAnchorID").next('img').attr('href')}
    else {
    $(this).hide(600);
    $("#ClickedAnchorID").next('img').attr('href',temp)
    }
    });
    }
```